# Want to list all music file on internal storage and external storage, but it cannot be done on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I am trying to access and list out all the music file on android Q or 10.
    I can do it with cursor and adding this projection

```
private static final String[] EXTERNAL_COLUMNS = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC,
            "\"" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + "\""
    };
```

but it is working upto api level 28. On android 10 it is showing
 `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column "content://media/external/audio/media"`.

I am adding this projection in cursorLoader.
I know there are some behavioral changes in Android 10 api level, but this thing is really freaking me out. Can anyone help me in that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but it is working upto api level 28" -- only because you are lucky, and I would not assume that it works across all device models. You do not need that constant to be returned in the `Cursor`. Simply remove it. Your bigger problem is that `DATA` has  never been reliable and it will not be returned on Android 10. Use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` to combine the `MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID` with the base `Uri` to get a `Uri` for the individual piece of content.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for the help, I am trying your tip. But what about the Android 10, is this an appropriate approach for it.

Comment: Querying `MediaStore` is fine for Android 10. Trying to use `DATA` is not.

Answer (score 2):

replace  **MediaStore.Audio.Media** with **MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns**

Comment: problem is with `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. It is showing as invalid column. Further i have already tried your suggestion earlier. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: how do you get the data ?

Comment: I simply put this projection in `new CursorLoader(
                this,
                baseUri,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
        );`. But it return error. I am trying @CommonsWare approach right now.

Comment: CursorLoader was deprecated in API level 28. @ShubhamKamlapuri

Answer (score 0):

I only use:-

```
 private static final String[] EXTERNAL_COLUMNS = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,

    };
```

as column, and pass null as projection.

then create uri for each file by

```
Uri uri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
```

after that i list all the uri, and get all other data of file through java.
It works, thanks @commonsWare.
It looks difficult, but it is far easy, just give it a try!

I am adding image fetch code for the reference

```
fun getAllDataPath(activity: Activity): MutableList<Uri> {
    val uriExternal: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val cursor: Cursor?
    val columnIndexID: Int
    val listOfAllImages: MutableList<Uri> = mutableListOf()
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    var imageId: Long
    cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(uriExternal, projection, null, null, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndexID = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            imageId = cursor.getLong(columnIndexID)
            val uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriExternal, "" + imageId)
            listOfAllImages.add(uriImage)
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return listOfAllImages
}
```

Please convert images to music and use it for your reference.

thanks

Comment: how did You get artist, tracknumber, albumart?

Comment: You can pass that data into columns(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ARTIST), or some java code as well. Only beware of DATA, it returns different information on different device!

Comment: can you please post more code you done ? It's really help us to better understand.